# How to filter an JS object and sort it by dates?

Tags: javascript

JS level: noob.

I have the following object which contains ~130 `trades` objects:

```
{
    "trades": {
        "model": "Trades_Information"
        "fields": {
                "orderCloseTime": "2019-12-19T16:20:56",
                [...]

        },
        "model": "Trades_Information"
        "fields": {
                "orderCloseTime": null,
                [...]
        },
        "model": "Trades_Information"
        "fields": {
                "orderCloseTime": 2019-12-17T16:20:56,
                [...]
        },

        [...]

}
```

Now I try to define a function that `splices` all objects that contain `orderCloseTime: null` and sort the remaining objects by date.

Using several SO threads and JS documentation I right now end up with this foolish attempt:

```
// loop and splice where if-condition is met
jQuery(trades).each(function (index){
    if(trades[index].fields.orderCloseTime == null){
                trades.splice(index,1);
                return false;
            }
    });

// define sort function

function trades_sort(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.orderCloseTime).getTime() - new Date(b.orderCloseTime).getTime();
}

// sort remaining objects

trades.sort(trades_sort);
```

When I run the code it only splices one object whereas it should splice six of them and the sort function literally doesn't sort at all.

Comment: Your JSON format isn’t even valid to begin with. Shouldn’t `trades` be an **array of objects**?

Comment: Since you mention you're new to this stuff, note that by the time you're using `trades`, you're not dealing with JSON anymore. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. So you don't have a "JSON object," you just have an object. Which (as Terry points out), probably contains an array of objects...?

Comment: I edited my initial question due to wrong json reference. Right, the object `trades` contains an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json issues aside as if your presented code is running then it's probably a copy over error... you just want to use filter and chain your sort operator:

```
trades = trades.filter(trade => !!trade.fields.orderCloseTime)
               .sort(trades_sort);
```

Comment: this is what I am looking for, thank you! I have one question regarding your answer. Is the line break valid JS coding style or just for visualizing the dingle steps within this answer? Just curious.. Thanks again.

Comment: The line breaks are valid style

Answer (score 3):

Fields in JSON should not be duplicated, you have only 2 keys
"fields" and "model"

so only two elements according your information will be loaded

The main problem is incorrect json

About the code i dont know what is trades and what is jQuery, but if trades is array of objects, then you can just filter it

```
trades.filter(v => v.fields.orderCloseTime)
```

With sort function everything is correct